# Getting a syntax error for python 3.8 while running a script

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to run this python script in https://github.com/dayeol/telegram-keyword-detector python and I get a syntax error in line 40 of the code.

```
 File "telebot.py", line 40
    if chat_type <> "private":
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Sorry for the formatting this is my first time asking a question here.

Comment: The syntax is `!=` not `<>`

Comment: `if chat_type != "private":`

Comment: I'm curious now what version that could run in. I thought `<>` was ditched before it ever saw life :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<>` operator was available in Python 2, but was removed in Python 3. If you want to use this script in Python 3, you need to replace the `<>` operator with `!=`.